# Is there an introduction to CiviCRM Entity anywhere?

Tags: drupal, civicrm-entity

After a year or two of occasionally trying to utilize CiviCRM Entity, I am no closer to understanding the module.

I've read every bit of documentation that I can find, which mostly pertain to Rules (which I try to use sparingly).

What I'd really love to see is an example of how to use it to create content types if that is possible (I have no idea!).

With as much as I try to integrate Civi and Drupal I am missing this golden goose!

Any suggestions?

Comment: You might have better luck posting a specific question about usage rather than a general one about documentation.

Comment: Updated the question.  But I don't even really know what to ask!

Comment: what is it that you cannot currently do that you want to achieve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the best introduction was this workshop: https://denver2015.civicrm.org/sessions/civicrmdrupal-integration-showcase  The PDF on that page is helpful; the video of the workshop is available here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2GpnrVGdrc.

Note also that there are significant plans underway for CiviCRM Entity announced this week, see here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2676756

Answer (score 1):

We are actually working on official CiviCRM Entity documentation now, but its not quite ready yet.

Until then you can review our blog articles with the CiviCRM Entity tag to learn more about specific features and updates to the module.

https://skvare.com/tags/civicrm-entity